# How to end "While Controller" on error and show whole progress in "View Results Tree"

Tags: jmeter

In my test plan I want to make java request and check how it was done by making jdbc request, But I don't exactly know when java request will change DB. I want to make several requests with waiting after each. And if JDBC request doesn't special changes after certain time stop whole test. After that I want to see progress where test plan stopped in view results tree.
BUT
If I use any stop-thread functions, there are no data in View Results Tree.
Haw can I do what I want with jmeter?
Thanks.

Comment: Why did you tag the question with [jrebel] tag? Doesn't seem to be related.

Comment: Omg, thank you) I meant jmeter.

Answer (score 0):

you can use a similar mechanism to the one described here:

- http://www.sourcepole.ch/2011/1/4/waiting-for-a-page-change-in-jmeter

Comment: Thank you for answer! But If I stop thread I won't see any progress in view results tree.

Comment: Could you clarify ? what do you mean by see progress in View Results Tree ?

Comment: Of course! I meant: After the thead stopped there are no data in view results tree. If I have 3 samplers I want to see something like: [OK-OK-FAIL]. But there is no data if thread stopped.